# Converting float values of big endian to little endian using C#

Tags: c#, arrays, floating-point, endianness

Is it possible to convert floats from big to little endian? I have a value from a big endian platform that I am sending via [UDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol) to a Windows process ([little endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)). This value is a float, but when I am trying BitConverter.ToSingle I always get 5.832204E-42, but it should be 36.000.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is a code snipped:

```
// Receive thread
private void ReceiveData()
{
    int count = 0;

    IPEndPoint remoteIP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("10.0.2.213"), port);
    client = new UdpClient(remoteIP);
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            IPEndPoint anyIP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
            byte[] data = client.Receive(ref anyIP);

            float x = BitConverter.ToSingle(data, 0);
            float y = BitConverter.ToSingle(data, 4);
            float z = BitConverter.ToSingle(data, 8);
            float alpha = BitConverter.ToSingle (data, 12);
            float theta = BitConverter.ToSingle (data, 16);
            float phi = BitConverter.ToSingle (data, 20);

            print(">> " + x.ToString() + ", "+ y.ToString() + ", "+ z.ToString() + ", " +
                  alpha.ToString() + ", "+ theta.ToString() + ", "+ phi.ToString());

            // Latest UDP packet
            lastReceivedUDPPacket=x.ToString()+" Packet#: "+count.ToString();
            count = count+1;
        }
```

Comment: Did you try just reversing the array first?

Comment: Please show us the data.

Comment: What's the input, and which value should be 36?

Comment: That's really not going to help us - we don't care how you *get* the data, we care about the values within the data. Please give us the sample data that you expect to give you 36.

Comment: @Jon 36.0 and 5.832204E-42 are endian-opposites, so it should indeed just be a straight end swap

Comment: @MarcGravell: Indeed. That's why I suggested reversing the array. As that wasn't working, I wanted to see the data. I suspect the OP reversed the *whole* array, rather than just the portion being read...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

36.0 and 5.832204E-42 are endian-opposites, so this is an endianness problem. On Windows / .NET, you are usually little-endian, so I'm guessing the data is big-endian. That means you need to reverse the data *for each value, separately* (not the entire array).

To write this in a way that is CPU-safe, the best option is to check `BitConverter.IsLittleEndian`, and compensate when necessary. For example:

```
public static float ReadSingleBigEndian(byte[] data, int offset)
{
    return ReadSingle(data, offset, false);
}
public static float ReadSingleLittleEndian(byte[] data, int offset)
{
    return ReadSingle(data, offset, true);
}
private static float ReadSingle(byte[] data, int offset, bool littleEndian)
{
    if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian != littleEndian)
    {   // other-endian; reverse this portion of the data (4 bytes)
        byte tmp = data[offset];
        data[offset] = data[offset + 3];
        data[offset + 3] = tmp;
        tmp = data[offset + 1];
        data[offset + 1] = data[offset + 2];
        data[offset + 2] = tmp;
    }
    return BitConverter.ToSingle(data, offset);
}
```

with:

```
float x= ReadSingleBigEndian(data, 0);
float y= ReadSingleBigEndian(data, 4);
float z= ReadSingleBigEndian(data, 8);
float alpha= ReadSingleBigEndian(data, 12);
float theta= ReadSingleBigEndian(data, 16);
float phi= ReadSingleBigEndian(data, 20);
```

Comment: Why not `Array.Reverse(data, offset, 4)`?

Comment: @phoog that would work, but does a **lot** of extra checks etc along the way (after all the checks, I *expect* it would be handled by the `extern` method, `TrySZReverse`). But yes, that would work.

Comment: Isn't `ReadSingle()` destructive; that is, won't it reverse bytes in the *original* array that is passed in?

Comment: @RobertHarvey yes, in this example it is; I wouldn't do it this way today - there's a big-endian and little-endian decoder in "buffers", IIRC, which the JIT can map to intrinsics - see `BinaryPrimitives`