# double value transferring in byte stream

Tags: c#, c++, arrays, double

C++

```
unsigned char lbytes[] = { 0x0A, 0x01, 0x02 };
unsigned char bytes[10];

double dbl = sin((double)i) * 10; 

i+=5; if (i == 360) i = 0;

memcpy(&bytes, &lbytes, 3);
cout << dbl << endl;
memcpy(&bytes[3], &dbl, sizeof(double));
```

C#

```
switch (m[1]) {
    case 0x01: {
        if (m.Length > 5) {
            double myval = Math.Round( BitConverter.ToDouble(m, 3), 2 );
```

but something is going wrong here, myval is alsways some very small value and with rount it's always 0.

question is: where is my mistake, I can see valid value in cout, I send 10 bytes, what is going wrong?

Comment: Aren't you copying your `double` beyond the boundary of your array?

Comment: Sounds like an endianness difference (big-endian vs little-endian). `BitConverter` uses CPU-endianness, so you might have to reverse the chunk. I posted some answers on that recently... try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13044200/converting-float-values-of-big-endian-to-little-c-sharp/13044715#13044715 (you'll need to expand to 8 bytes for double, obviously)

Comment: that's just my fault of sending only 10 bytes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you send *only* ten bytes. A double is *eight* byte, plus your header of three bytes which means that you should send 11 bytes.

If you adjust your `bytes` array and send the correct length it should work.